How to execute python class with marker
I have created a class which has a parent and one base class.
Both classes have markers.
I want to run and execute a test with that particular marker only.
Example: if i execute pytest -m "Nevada" or pytest -m Nevada
Then only Nevada class test should execute and not Quebec.
Currently when I execute this command, both class instances were created and test_txt_24102_2 was executed for both instances.
Below is the code:
@pytest.mark.Nevada
class TestNevada:

    def step_1(self):
        print("Step 1 for Nevada")

    def step_2(self):
        print("Step 2 for Nevada")

    def step_3(self):
        print("Step 3 for Nevada")

    def test_txt_24102_2(self):
        self.step_1()
        self.step_2()
        self.step_3()



@pytest.mark.G2S
@pytest.mark.Quebec
class TestQuebec(Nevada):

    def step_1(self):
        print("Step 1 for Quebec")
    def step_2(self):
        print("Step 2 for Quebec")


Since your classes inherit from one another, the derived class will also inherit the superclass's marks.
Furthermore, since the Nevada class isn't named Test..., it won't be introspected for tests at all.
You'd need something like
import pytest


@pytest.mark.Nevada
class TestNevada:
    def test_x(self):
        pass


@pytest.mark.G2S
@pytest.mark.Quebec
class TestQuebec:
    def test_y(self):
        pass

and then things work as you might expect.
$ pytest test_78706988.py -vv -m Quebec
collected 2 items / 1 deselected / 1 selected
test_78706988.py::TestQuebec::test_y PASSED
$ pytest test_78706988.py -vv -m Nevada
collected 2 items / 1 deselected / 1 selected
test_78706988.py::TestNevada::test_x PASSED

If you do need multiple test cases to derive from some shared class, make a third class that's not marked and inherit from there, like
import pytest


class StateTestBase:
    def get_state_name(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def test_state_name(self):
        assert self.get_state_name().isalpha()


@pytest.mark.Nevada
class TestNevada(StateTestBase):
    def get_state_name(self):
        return "Nevada"


@pytest.mark.G2S
@pytest.mark.Quebec
class TestQuebec(StateTestBase):
    def get_state_name(self):
        return "Quebec"

–
$ pytest test_78706988.py -vv
collected 2 items

test_78706988.py::TestNevada::test_state_name PASSED                                                                                                            [ 50%]
test_78706988.py::TestQuebec::test_state_name PASSED                                                                                                            [100%]

However, in that case I'd probably just use fixtures instead.
